# How can I cause my python program to "sleep" without the sleep function

Tags: python

I've been asked the question:
Define a second function which, when called, will “sleep” for approximately three seconds, and while doing so will display a “z” on the screen about every ½ a second.  Do not use the sleep function to accomplish this task as we have not studies.

I do not know how to do this, please help

Comment: Can you measure the passing of time using the [**`time`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) module?

Comment: He has asked us to come up with a "hack" solution based upon loops, defining functions, and string manipulation

Comment: SO is limited to _practical_, answerable questions. This is answerable, but doing something deliberately inefficient is the opposite of practical, so it's off topic here.

Comment: I already told you of such a way -- the `select` call timeout argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `time` module:

```
from time import time

start_time = time()
end_time = start_time + 3
next_z = start_time + 0.5

while next_z < end_time:
    if time() > next_z:
        print('z')
        next_z += 0.5
```